# Parse int, double, and String from a String in Java

Tags: java

I have to do an assignment in my Java class using the `Scanner` method to input an integer (number of items), a string (name of the item), and a double (cost of the item). We have to use `Scanner.nextLine()` and then parse from there.

Example:

```
System.out.println("Please enter grocery item (# Item COST)");
String input = kb.nextLine();
```

The user would input something like: `3 Captain Crunch 3.5`

Output would be: `Captain Crunch #3 for $10.5`

The trouble I am having is parsing the int and double from the string, but also keeping the string value.

Answer (score 3):

1. First of all, split the string and get an array.
2. Loop through the array.
3. Then you can try to parse those strings in array to their respective type.

**For example:**
In each iteration, see if it is integer. Following example checks the first element to be an integer.

```
string[0].matches("\\d+")
```

Or you can use **try-catch** as follow (not recommended though)

```
try{
   int anInteger = Integer.parseInt(string[0]);
   }catch(NumberFormatException e){

   }
```

Comment: Why looping? You already know, that it should contain 3 elements.

Comment: @Tom Just in case :-) Easier to program, may be

Comment: Thank you for your help! :) Never used stackoverflow before but it's already proving to be quite useful.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question you could use [`String.indexOf(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29) and [`String.lastIndexOf(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29) like

```
String input = "3 Captain Crunch 3.5";
int fi = input.indexOf(' ');
int li = input.lastIndexOf(' ');
int itemNumber = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(0, fi));
double price = Double.parseDouble(input.substring(li + 1));
System.out.printf("%s #%d for $%.2f%n", input.substring(fi + 1, li),
            itemNumber, itemNumber * price);
```

Output is

```
Captain Crunch #3 for $10.50
```

Comment: Looks like "get 3 for the price of one" :).

Comment: @Tom Fixed, but it was one for the price of one.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String message = sc.nextLine();//take the message from the command line
    String temp [] = message.split(" ");// assign to a temp array value
    int number = Integer.parseInt(temp[0]);// take the first value from the message
    String name = temp[1]; // second one is name.
    Double price = Double.parseDouble(temp[2]); // third one is price
    System.out.println(name +  " #" + number + " for $ "  + number*price ) ;
```

Comment: This seems extremely useful, my only question is what if the name is more than one word? For example, Captain Crunch or something like that?